# Array in an array shuffles values between each other

Tags: java

So I have array in an array, that looks like this:

```
public class randomvalues {
public double[] pl() {
    double result[]={};
    final double[] values1 = {49.131389, 49.106756,55.786031,55.78468};
    final double[] values2 = {10.762975, 10.707722,59.920678,59.92042};
    final double[] values3 = {-80.187194, -80.31491, 25.753951, 25.748076};
    final double[] values4 = {10.229381,10.20595,59.744406,59.743368};
    final double[][] con = {values1,values2,values3,values4};
    final Random random = new Random();
    int what = new Random().nextInt(con.length);
    result = (con[what]);
    return result;}
```

When i run this class, I receive something like this 
49.131389 10.20595 55.786031 59.92042 so its a new array which consist of parts from different ones.

But I want to receive one of four given array with its original values like
49.131389 49.106756 25.753951 25.748076

Please help.

Comment: You haven't explained the meaning behind those numbers. As your question is currently phrased, the answer would be just `{49.131389, 49.106756, 25.753951, 25.748076}`, but that's obviously not what you want. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You're going to have to build your array with a few steps if you want to mix and match it.

Comment: When you are using `random` inside pl function, How can you expect some particular output?

Comment: I'm trying to recieve one random array from four given arrays and use its values in another class. But instead of it i recieve new array which consist of parts from different array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, what you want to do is :

```
  randomvalues ran = new randomvalues();
  double[] arr=countries.pl();
  double maxf = arr[0];
  double minf = arr[1];
  double maxd = arr[2];
  double mind = arr[3];
```

You are calling `countries.pl()` four times, that's why you are getting different(probably different) array every time.